# Why can't view controller height be adjusted

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

Xcode5, interface builder - add a view controller.  Set to free form and set height to say 1,000.  I'm placing labels and images and when first setting up the view I don't know what the height is so I set it pretty large to give myself some working room.  I add in scroll view, labels etc., but then comes 5:00 and I have to stop.  I shut down XCode and log out.  Next Day: open up project and continue working and once everything is set up and then go to change my height of the view controller to fit my content.  The value I set the day before is now permanent.  It can't be changed.  Auto layout or not, I can no longer change the value for my view's height.  Autolayout and constraints overrides anything I try in code.
My only way around this is to start early and make sure I have everything set up (labels, images) so I can set view's height before shutting down for the night.
How does everyone else get around this?

[image]

Comment: You said you added a ViewController, so you're using Storyboards? Can you post a screenshot of this VC and whatever is containing it?

Comment: Just added the screenshot above.

Answer (score 4):

To update the height, go back into the `UIViewController`s Size Inspector. The value you set there will be what your View is set to.

It will either look like this if it's still on Freeform:

[image: ViewController Freeform size]

Or this if it somehow got set back to Fixed:

[image: ViewController Fixed size]

Comment: The view controller doesn't have anything for the size inspector attributes.  Only the subviews.

Comment: You should see one of the two added images from above if you are looking in the right spot.

Comment: The fact that after setting it to Freeform it appears you can change the height/width values in the view definitely seems like a bug though. I would submit a radar! https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/

Comment: For View COntroller in size inspector was hidden so I never saw that.  thanks! Unfortunately its closing time and I'll have to wait till tomorrow to play with this some more.